# AJAX not passing variable to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm semi-new to PHP and I'm working on a website's dashboard page where an administrator can see all existing admins, there's a button on each admin name's row that's supposed to check the privileges of each admin (access to article editing, clients payment information, etc).

When the admin clicks on that button, a div slides in the page and it shows this window:

Admin Privileges Dialog
[image]

Where it shows the current permissions.

I have a var called "*admin_id*" which is updated whenever a button is clicked, because as I'm using "foreach" to iterate the list of admins, I also have their "*admin_id*" linked to each of these buttons.

My point is to use ajax so an admin can change another admin's permissions without reloading the page and reopening this little dialog so I'm trying to pass the variable "*admin_id*" to my PHP file where I have my SQL and returning it

**check_privileges.php**

```
<?php

    include("../../includes/dbconnect.php");


    $admin_id = $_GET['admin_id'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE admin_id = $admin_id";
    $sql_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);

    // storing results in array
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)){

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    // returning response in JSON format
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

and this is the page's file where I'm requesting the ajax, in get method, to receive the results from the database:

**users.php**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    // We now have the admin_id of the user correspondent to the row we're clicking, declaring the admin_id variable outside of the scope of the function so I can access it anywhere

    var admin_id;
// update the variable value with the value of the admin_id of the button
    $(".row-user-perm").find("button").click( function() {
        var admin_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(admin_id);

    });

    $('.button-priv').click( function(){

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = "get";
        var url = "includes/check_privileges.php";
        var data = {admin_id: admin_id};
        var asynchronous = true;
        var success = function (data) {
                    console.log(data.report.data[0].article_flag);
                };

        ajax.open(method, url, data, asynchronous);
        // sending ajax request
        ajax.send();

        // receiving response from data.php
        var data = {};
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                
                // converting JSON back to array
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(data); // for debugging
                // alert(data[0].article_flag);

                var article_flag = data[0].article_flag;
        
                if (article_flag == 1) {
                    console.log("Article flag is 1!");
                    $('#article-perm-svg').removeClass('no-perm');
                    $('#article-perm-svg').addClass('has-perm');
                }else{
                    alert("article flag is not 1!");
                };
            };


        };
    });
```

And when I click a "Check Privileges" button, I get this error in the browser's console:

JSON console error

[image]

JSON console error trace?

[image]

I know the problem is the **$_GET['admin_id']** being empty so it's not receiving any value because if I use an existing admin_id, I get the results in the page and everything working.

What am I doing wrong? I've read online that I don't need to use a post method to do this, but I've tried both anyway and nothing worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: An `includes` directory typically holds files intended to be `included()` and not accessed directly from the client. You might want to rethink your naming conventions.

Comment: Hey @Quentin I wasn't worried about that due to this being a restricted page to one or two admins, hence not using prepared statements

Comment: Be worried. Admins can be targeted by CSRF attacks as much as anyone.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a problem of the browser, or the server? Is the request sent properly? Does the server handle it properly? Does it send the expected response? Is the response handled properly by your browser?

Comment: Also, there is never a good reason to write insecure code. Get used to writing secure code in all cases, to learn it. You don't want to get into the situation that you forgot to check your application after the access control scheme got changed such that more users can access your route.....

Comment: @NicoHaase As I mentioned, the request is sent properly, if I remove the option to send any data and just replace the "$admin_id" variable in my SQL php file with an existing admin_id of my database, it returns the array containing that admin's rows, it just doesn't work when I try to send the data through the AJAX as the $_GET value is never received on the PHP file

Comment: If the request does not contain the GET value you expect, I would assume that you don't send the request properly. Have you checked this in your browser's network console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument to `open` is if the request should be handled asynchronously or not. It isn't where you put the data.

If you were making a POST request, then you would put the data in as the first argument to the `send` method… but that doesn't accept a plain object.

Since you are making a GET request, you need to encode the data into the query string of the URL that you pass as the second argument to `open`.

```js
const admin_id = "12345";
const relativeUrl = 'includes/check_privileges.php';
const url = new URL(relativeUrl, location.href);
url.searchParams.append('admin_id', admin_id);
console.log(url.toString())
```

Comment: I'm not quite getting, so the "data" needs to be passed as the second argument being that I'm used the get method? And how and why do I need to encode the data into the query (not sure what that means) being that I don't want the page to reload

Comment: @AntónioLima — The entire point of `$_GET` is that it reads the data from the query. If you don't put it there then it won't be in `$_GET`.

Comment: I see.. Can you insert your code in my ajax snipper so I can understand better, please? I'm new to AJAX and I'm still confused to the interpretation of your code or its placement in mine, thanks for the attention, @Quentin

Comment: It literally replaces the way you are currently defining your `url` variable (and the bits I said you should remove).

Comment: Ohh, so the data gets sent inside the URL, I get it, do I need to set the variable to a const tho? or can I just insert it there as a variable

Comment: Use whatever variable type makes sense.

Comment: The locations is giving me an "id=undefinded" for some reason, I don't understand why, when I've even pushed the previous function inside this one to check if it was a problem of the variable being outside the scope or something

Comment: You have two different variables named `admin_id`. You are setting one and reading the other.

Comment: You are right! Sorry for my sloppyness and thank you for your time!